# Xubuntu 15.04 fails to boot into a live session from a live USB, but only when my SSD is plugged in

Tags: boot, partitioning, xubuntu, live-usb, ssd

Specs: Xubuntu 15.04, GTX 770, i5-4690k, 8 GB RAM, Corsair SSD, Hitachi HDD.

Whenever I boot into a live session, it always fails to boot when I have my SSD plugged in. This is most likely the result of [my recent struggle with partitions](http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmasterrace/comments/36oitl/welp_i_may_have_managed_to_corrupt_my_data/), but that was on my HDD. My SSD contains my OS partitions. I've also [asked people on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/36over/can_someone_explain_to_me_how_this_is_possible/) about this, but they weren't able to find a solution. Please help, I'm at my wits end, I don't understand what is going on, some people on Reddit are even calling this witchcraft.

Comment: What are you using to boot the live system with?

Comment: 32 GB USB flash drive, made bootable with Rufus and a Xubuntu 15.04 ISO on Windows.

Comment: More details, please: You say "it always fails to boot," but that's imprecise. What happens when you try? Do you see any error messages? Does it boot the wrong thing? How are you attempting to boot the external medium? (Via the firmware's built-in boot manager? If so, what option are you picking and what other options are available?)

Comment: I select the drive in BIOS, click "try w/o installing", and the "loading circle" spins for a minute, and then disappears, and the live session never loads up. It just freezes with the word "Xubuntu" and the blue background. I don't want to pick the other options, I don't want to install the OS, I just want to be able to edit my files with a live session.

Comment: For some random reason, Windows no longer boots, but my live usb does. I'm gonna leave this question open, because I'd like feedback on the general problem that I've been having in the links, which is causing things to randomly break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the kernel that comes from LTS (3.19).
Noticed that having **persistent** on the command line and NO caspar-rw FILE will stop the boot process in busybox. Adding the casper-rw file removes that problem. My work-around for now is use a small casper-rw file AND and home-rw partition which cover the remainder of the thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use kernel 3.19, kernel 3.18 and older and kernel 4.0 and newer work fine.